# How do I add checks for my command script in PySimpleGUI

Tags: python, terminal, gnome, pysimplegui

I am writing a simple GUI which runs a set of git hub commands in terminal. I was wondering how I can add checks for each command script before moving on?

For example: git fetch; CHECK if git fetch is successful; git checkout origin/prod/20230426; CHECK if git checkout origin/prod/20230426 is successful;

Here is my cod:

```
import PySimpleGUI as sg    # type: ignore
import textwrap
import os
import subprocess
import sys
import re

sg.theme('DarkAmber')

layout = [

    [sg.Text("Github script  ")],
    [sg.Button("Run Script")]

]

window = sg.Window('Window TItle', layout)


while True:
    event, values = window.read()
    if event in (sg.WIN_CLOSED, 'Exit', '-YAML-EXIT-'):
        break
    elif re.match(r'.*-EXIT-$', event):
        break

    elif event == 'Run Script':

        command= ('gnome-terminal -- bash -c "cd ~/Test; git fetch; git checkout origin/prod/20230426; git checkout -b jmesia/testbranch; exec bash -i"')
        ret = subprocess.run(command, capture_output=True, shell=True)
        print(ret.stdout.decode())

window.close()
```

I think it works fine now but  eventually I know I would have to make checks so I can make sure each command is successful before moving on to the next one.

Comment: Usually, the return code of the command will indicate success or failure; you can also check additional things, like seeing if the actual effects of the command were successfully executed, but usually the return code is a good enough indication of success or failure for a lot of standard commands.